# Dance pad in XNA

Tags: xna

Is there any class that supports Dance pad in XNA? Maybe it's treated just like regular pad?
I don't have any access to dance pad, and it's quite hard to find any usefull info in the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dance pad would work just as any other game controller, although you would have to figure out the mapping between buttons and the gamepad button enumeration. You should be able to use the [XNA Input Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.aspx) just like normal, although I'm pretty sure it will not work on the Xbox 360 unless it was made specifically for the console.

Comment: @Kersny: Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for. I'm gonna use it  on PC.